# Laravel 5 One to Many Issue

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, one-to-many

I’ve followed all the Laravel documentation on relationships but am still having a problem.

I have two tables:

Qualifications
-id
-code
-title
-level details

Components 
-id
-name
-qualification_id

Every qualification has many components and every component has one qualification.

This is my Qualification Model:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Qualification extends Model {

   protected $fillable = [

        'code',
        'title',
        'type',
        'level',
        'details',

   ];

   protected $table = 'qualifications';
   public $timestamps = true;

    public function component()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App/Component');
    }
}
```

Component Model:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Component extends Model {

    protected $fillable = [

        'name',
        'qualification_id',

    ];

    protected $table = 'components';
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function qualification()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Qualification');

    }

}
```

I want to show the related units when I view a qualification.

Qualification controller:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Component;
use App\Qualification;
use App\Http\Requests\QualificationRequest;

class QualificationController extends Controller {

public function show($id)
{
    $qualification = Qualification::find($id);

    $component = Qualification::find(1)->component;

    return view('qualifications.show', compact('qualification','component'));
}
```

Here is the view 'qualifications.show’

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')

    <h1>{{ $qualification->title }} </h1>

    <div class="body">{{ $qualification->code }}</div>

    <h2> Units </h2>

    @foreach ($component as $component)


        <div class="body"> {{ $component->name }} </div>

    @endforeach

@stop
```

But I keep getting an error:

FatalErrorException in Model.php line 893: Class 'App/Component' not found

Please can someone help? I’ve been at this for a few days and read everything I could find but to no avail and I’m losing hope.

Thanks,

Jenny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect:

```
return $this->hasMany('App/Component');
```

while you define the other one:

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Qualification');
```

it should '\' as far as i remember.
and also, `$component = Qualification::find(1)->component()->get();` so, it will be the an array of query result not some query builder thingy.